# ALBD SERVER ISSUES

Tags: clearcase, rhel

Working in Red Hat Linux trying to build RPMs that are accessed via Clearcase vobs but keep on getting a recurring error which states, 'unable to find albd-server on host ', 'Unable to contact view - clearcase object not found' and 'Unknown host  - Name or service not know'. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? What type of view?

Comment: Using the latest version and using a dynamic view.

Comment: "`unable to find albd-server on host xxx`" Is '`xxx`' the same server as the Red Hat Linux where you are using your dynamic view?

Comment: Personally, I would strongly recommend opening a support case on this issue. StackOverflow is not exactly the best forum for a "conversation," and there are questions that need to be asked that shouldn't really be done in a public forum.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue in the end by using clearmake -V in the makeall script. Because I'm working with shareable DOs this enabled me to avoid winking in between views. Thankfully it built successfully this time but instead of it being in the build error log it appeared as a test failure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the `vobrpc_server_log` on the ClearCase Vob Server.
As seen in this technote (for an older version of ClearCase, but still relevant)

> Attempts to mount a VOB results in the following error:
>
> ```
> ClearCase Object Not Found
> ```
>
> This error may get reported in the VOBRPC error log:
>
> ```
> 01/06/2006 09:24:34 vobrpc_server(5016): Error: vobrpc_server.exe(5016):
> Error: Unable to get VOB tag registry information for replica uuid
>        "db7983f9.052d498a.915f.bb:f9:0e:b0:b4:ea": 
>        ClearCase object not found
> ```
>
> This error may get reported in the vob_scrubber log:
>
> ```
> vob_scrubber: Error: Unable to get VOB tag registry information 
> for replica uuid "db7983f9.052d498a.915f.bb:f9:0e:b0:b4:ea": 
> ClearCase object not found
> ```
>
> This error will occur when trying to mount the VOB before the VOB tag creation is complete.
> This would be due to a timing issue where the `cleartool mkvob` and `cleartool mount` operations are done via a script, and maybe a longer pause is required before the VOB is mounted on a remote host.
> This would also be true in an environment where the VOB creation takes several moments to complete, and there is an extended period before the VOB tag is available for users to mount.
>
> Note: This does not occur as a result of the `cleartool mount` that is executed automatically during the `cleartool mkvob` operation.
>
> - **Cause 2**: The VOB tag may still exist even though the VOB storage (or VOB server host) are no longer available in the ClearCase network.
>   This will happen as a result of improper removal of the VOB storage.
> - **Cause 3**:  The server storage location (network share or export) is not available.
>   When mounting a VOB, the location that the VOB is stored must be accessible from the host that you are trying to mount the VOB.
> - **Cause 4**: If the VOB is not yet tagged in the primary region of the VOB server.
>   This is applicable to environments that have multiple registry regions.

Comment: I can't agree with this one. Everything depends on the context. And you would not normally be getting errors relating to mkvob and mount during a build.

Comment: @BrianCowan I agree. This is more a "first, check your server logs" type of answer. Opening a support case is certainly the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a clearmake build? Does it complete? (Winkin and shopping failures USUALLY don't cause a build failure.) What is printing those errors? Clearmake? Another ClearCase tool?

What is the **exact** version of ClearCase? If 9.0.1.x, the patch level and your license type may matter, as some older 9.0.1.x releases had an issue where you would get "extra" errors if you had albd contact failures and you use Rational Common Licensing.